# flutter delete an image from firebase storage

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I need to delete an image from firebase storage. I have a function that uploads an image to firebase storage, but i don’t know how to delete image from firebase storage.

here is the function of upload an image

```
Future uploadImageToFirebase(BuildContext context,File file) async {
    String fileName = basename(file.path);
    StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('uploads/$fileName');

    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = firebaseStorageRef.putFile(file);

    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
            (value) {
          print(value);
          setState(() {
            widget.photoAssetPaths[visiblePhotoIndex] = value;
          });
        });
  }
```

can any one help me write a method to delete an image based on its url from the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is quite simple to do. This is a simple function I wrote to delete my files from the storage bucket.

This is a simple method that takes the URL of the file to be deleted as a parameter:

```
deleteFile(url)
```

The next thing is to get the reference from the URL:

```
await FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url).delete();
```

Please note that this code is in a `try-catch` block so as to catch any unforeseen error.

Here's the complete code:

```
Future<void> deleteFile(String url) async {
  try {
    await FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url).delete();
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error deleting db from cloud: $e");
  }
}
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: I get a `'!path.contains('//')': a document path must not contain "//"` any advice?

Comment: I think you should recheck your URL string. THere's a possibility you're appending a string which ends with a "/" with another which starts with a "/"

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a [`Reference` to the file](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/delete.html) in Cloud Storage, you can call [`delete`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/delete.html) on that reference. To map a download URL to a reference, you can call [`storage.refFromUrl()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/FirebaseStorage/refFromURL.html).

So, given the download URL, that should be something like:

```
FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromUrl(downloadUrl).delete();
```

Comment: can you give me all steps plz

Comment: The code in my answer is pretty much all you need. If you're having a hard time making that work, I suggest you show what you tried already to delete a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just delete it from the firebase dashboard or do you want the user to be able to delete an image from a button or something?

Comment: no i need to delete it when click a button in the app.

Comment: OP specifically asked for a method to use to delete the file. Please consider updating your answer.